# How i can find the file format in linux programatically?

Tags: linux, file, timezone, format, file-type

I need to upload the timezone data file to target board through FTP. The timezone data file name is renamed or modified as 'time_zone_info'. So i need to verify the uploaded file is timezone data format or not? FTP will accept any file with name time_zone_info. I need to verify the file format, If it is timezone data format then i need to keep that file in target board otherwise need to throw error to FTP

Comment: [`man file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command))

Comment: In our target board, we are using kernel 2.4 version and the busybox utility also old one. the think is 'file' utility is not present in this. So, What should i do for this? How i can get source code for this file utility?

Comment: Google for it. Hint: `libmagic`

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the first bytes of the file.  In the case of TZ data, the first 4 bytes should be `TZif` (version 2 of the file will be `TZif2`)

In Python you could do something like:

```python
def check_tz(fname):
    fd = open(fname, 'rb')

    result = fd.read(4) != 'Tzif'

    fd.close()

    return result
```

If need to do it with shell, then you can use the utility `file`.  You could also use libmagic or do the producedure in the function in the language of your preference.